# Js regex needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a big problem trying to write some regular expressions for some string comparison. I have trying for over 2 hours now and lost my patience.
In short what I try to do get the letters after the `cgid` and before the end-of-line or next `&` in the following strings:

`#cgid=neu` and `#cgid=neu&start=2`

I have tried using `stringVar.match("/&cgid=(.*?)&/")` but it returns `null`.

I have also to get the last word after `/` in the following string:

```
"/s/SiteName/neu".
```

I know this is easy but it seems I am too hard headed to learn regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you show strings with `#cgid=...` and then try to match it with `&cgid=...`? That makes no sense at all. Regexes are perfectly logical, by definition of the term "REGULAR expression". It's easy:

```
stringVar.match(/\bcgid=([^&]+)/);
```

Your desired target will be in the `[1]` index of the array.

For your "last word after `/`" part, try this:

```
stringVar.split("/").pop();
```

Comment: the # was a typo, I forgot to remove it

Comment: Okay. I replaced `#` with `\b` in my answer.

Comment: both work perfectly, the second one should have been obvious, but I was too irritated to think. as a side question, how long did it took you to learn regular expressions and can you recommend some good tutorial?

Comment: What's with the cocky attitude? Regular expressions are logical, sure, but they are not inherently simple just because they're called "regular" expressions. There's *plenty* of tricky examples of regular expressions and *plenty* of pitfalls where you easily get false positives or false negatives. I could find any number of examples on the internet of non-trivial tasks solved with regular expressions that become *hugely* complex, so please curb the attitude when you're helping someone that has difficulties with them.

Comment: @viktor I just read PHP's [PCRE manual](http://php.net/pcre) to learn basica regex syntax, and went from there.

Answer (score 0):

`\w+=([^&]+)`

You have that in first capturing griup here

Comment: This will match a lot of things it shouldn't.

Comment: @pguardiario And yet it has two upvotes... I think I'll rectify that :p

Answer (score 0):

Try group 1 from:

```
cgid=(.*?)(&.*)?
```